# How to locate an array in a php object with no key

Tags: php, json, csv, oop

I have a database of zip codes from The Zip Code Database Project that came as a .csv file. I converted it to json and it has no key for each array, they look like this:

```
[
    {
      "zipcode": 35004,
      "state abbreviation": "AL",
      "latitude": 33.606379,
      "longitude": -86.50249,
      "city": "Moody",
      "state": "Alabama"
    }
]
```

I have figured out how to search all of the arrays and locate a matching zip code but I can't figure out how to make that search return data about the array that it found it in.

I can search like this:

```
$filename = './assets/data/zips.json';
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);
    $zipCodes = json_decode($data);

    $inputZip = 55555;

    foreach ($zipCodes as $location) {
        if ($inputZip == $location->zipcode) {
            echo "Success";
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how I can use this search (or a better idea) to store the latitude and longitude associated with the searched zip code to two variables? I have wasted nearly my whole weekend on this so any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Also, I have no issue using the raw csv file to perform this function, I just couldn't get as far as I did with json.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out the index of an array by a property of the array items, use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get just the values of that column/property, then use [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search) to find the index.

```
<?php
$inputZip = 35004;

$index = array_search($inputZip, array_column($zipCodes, 'zipcode')); // 0

print_r($zipCodes[$index]); // the entire object
```

https://3v4l.org/TAXQq

Comment: I think you would also agree with the edit. To use `array_column` you need `json_decode` with `assoc` set to `true` to get associative array as result.

Comment: no you dont need an array of arrays to use array_column. look at 3v4l the example provided.

Comment: Yes you are right it works with objects, if you change it you get an array in this example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a2c1407f3c7341f29669e04ca827ea825bd20222 but shouldn't all the entries matching the $zipCode 35004 be returned in your code or it just return the first one?

Comment: You are correct about `array_column` though there was an addition in `PHP` 7.0.0 Added the ability for the input parameter to be an array of objects. I was remembering prior that version, my bad you are correct on this one. But you code still returns one result only. I thought the result should be all the entries that match the criteria not only the first one.

Comment: I mean if more than one entry is found and has same zipCode but different lat-long shouldn't all of those entries be the output of the above? In the above comment there is a sandbox example that returns only one result but two pass the criteria since they have zipCode 35004

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code:

```
foreach ($zipCodes as $index => $location) { // index is a key
    if ($inputZip == $location->zipcode) {
        echo "Index is ".$index;
        break;
    }
}
var_dump($zipCodes[$index]);
```

I should note that it seems you are doing something wrong because you don`t suppose to store your data like this and loop through array all the time.

Answer (score 0):

To get the keys of an array that is filtered due to certain parameters that must be met you could use `array_keys` and `array_filter`.

**For Example**

```
$array = [1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1];

$out = array_filter($array,function($v) {
    return $v == 2;
});
print_r(array_keys($out));
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 8
)
```

Try the above example in [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e9f3a4b9db1128dc1ec5dbc611d10d78a33360e0)

**To match your actual data structure.**

```
$json = '[{"zipcode": 35004,"state abbreviation": "AL","latitude": 33.606379,"longitude": -86.50249,"city": "Moody","state": "Alabama"},{"zipcode": 35004,"state abbreviation": "AL","latitude": 33.606379,"longitude": -86.50249,"city": "Moody","state": "Alabama"},{"zipcode": 35005,"state abbreviation": "AL","latitude": 33.606579,"longitude": -86.50649,"city": "Moody","state": "Alabama"}]';
$array = json_decode($json);
$out = array_filter($array, function($v) use ($inputZip) {
    return $v->zipcode == $inputZip; // for the below output $inputZip=35004 
});
print_r(array_keys($out));
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
)
```

Try the example in [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5ae4db18751f92768696599b21bb0d7163626307)

Comment: imo, answers need to match the OP's question and provided mcve code

Comment: @LawrenceCherone indeed. But for some people it is not needed. They get the idea. ;)